# Map CapsLock to Escape in OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: keyboard, capslock, osx-yosemite

I used to use [Seil](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html.en) to map my Caps Lock to Escape, but this no longer works in OS X 10.10. Attempts at doing the same thing with `setxkbmap` and `xmodmap` have also failed.

Are there other options for mapping the CapsLock to Escape in OS X 10.10?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the right combination. Change the key mapping from Seil [1]. In the keyboard preferences - Leave modifiers as it is (without changing the default behaviors for Caps Lock). I also installed Karabiner [2] but I am not whether it's really needed.

[1] - https://github.com/tekezo/Seil
[2] - https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

Comment: So, from your answer, it appears that just using Seil will work?

Comment: Thank you! It's the only thing that has worked for me using El Captain